# Export filtered/queried GoogleSpreadsheet to pdf via AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, filter

I have a spreadsheet with data of the day of some students (name, date, lesson, presence, teacher).

I want to export a filtered list via pdf with 2 criterias:

1. name
2. time frame

In the spreadsheet itself I can filter this by query. But I have no idea how I can do this via script to export it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the export function via a menu. It will save to your root drive after you run the function.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function onOpen() {
 
    // Add a menu item based on properties (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE).
  var items = [
    {name: 'Export', functionName: 'exportToPDF'},
  ];
    ss.addMenu('Export', items);
    }       
    
function exportToPDF() {
var sheetName = "Sheet1";
var pdfName = "My Created PDF "+Date();
var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

//Copy whole spreadsheet
var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf"))

//delete redundant sheets
var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
}
}

var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
//repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references) 
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

//save to pdf
var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(theBlob);

//Delete the temporary sheet
DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);

 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('New PDF file created in the root of your Google Drive')
}
```